# iText7 read image from PDF and create a buffered image

Tags: java, pdf, bufferedimage, itext7

I'm trying to read PDF document and extract images from it.

When I hit `EventType#RENDER_IMAGE` I try to create a `BufferedImage` from the `PdfImageXObject`. If it contains `SMask` key I can create the transparency successfully but when it contains `Mask` key I don't have any indirect object to create the transparency from it. Instead I have integer array of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] values which I don't know how to handle.

Additionally, the same problem exists for me with `ImageMask` key that the value of it is a boolean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried in terms of code?

Comment: *"Instead I have integer array of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] values which I don't know how to handle."* - *In PDF 1.3, the Mask entry in an image dictionary may be an array specifying a range of colours to be
masked out. Samples in the image that fall within this range shall not be painted, allowing the existing
background to show through.* (ISO 32000-2, section 8.9.6.4 "Colour key masking")

Comment: My question is how to mask the image with the given array if I already have a ```BufferedImage``` @AlexeySubach.

Comment: I still don't understand this range. Is it [R, G, B, R, G, B] from-to range?

Comment: *"Is it [R, G, B, R, G, B] from-to range?"* - No, it's [r, R, g, G, b, B], component-wise ranges.